# Is it possible to refer to a dictionary name via user input?

Tags: python

I want my users to be able to edit a dictionary value from outside the IDLE, by inputting its name and a value.

My unsuccessful code simplified:

```
input = ("Input dictionary name")
[USER HAS INPUT "exampleDictionary"]
newValue = ("Input new value")
[USER HAS INPUT 5]


exampleDictionary = {
  "value1": 20,
  "value2": 35
}

input["value1"] = newValue
```

Ideally, this would change exampleDictionary's "value1" to 5.

Comment: This is not a valid python code.

Comment: You're making a common mistake beginning Python coders make: confusing data (what users enter when the program is running) with code (what programmers enter to create the program). Typically, you should avoid having users guess at variable names and access them like this - instead use a dictionary.

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1):

I this the best way for doing that is like this

```
dict_list = {
    "exampleDictionary"  : {
        "value1": 20,
        "value2": 35
    }
}
input = ("Input dictionary name")
[USER HAS INPUT "exampleDictionary"]
newValue = ("Input new value")
[USER HAS INPUT 5]

dict_list[input]["value1"] = newValue
print(dict_list)
```

Output:

```
{
    "exampleDictionary"  : {
        "value1": 5,
        "value2": 35
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As other users have suggested, you probably don't need to do this. Internal structure of the application (that includes variable names) should not be exposed to users.

---

You can use `eval` method. It lets a program run code within the program itself.

```
exampleDictionary = {"value1": 20,"value2": 35}

input1 = "exampleDictionary"
input2 = 5

d = eval(input1)
d["value1"] = input2


print(d["value1"])
# 5
```

But note that using `eval` is considered a *bad* practice. So, you can use following code to get variable from current module, and update it's value.

```
import sys

thismodule = sys.modules[__name__]
d = thismodule.__getattribute__(input1)
d["value1"] = input2

print(d["value1"])
# 5
```

Comment: I think it's better to avoid using ***eval***.

Comment: But seriously, don't do this. It's slower and has more problems in general than just using a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
master_dict = {
    "my_dict" : { "value1": 20, "value2": 35}
}

dict_n = input("Input dictionary name:\n") # my_dict
if dict_n in master_dict: # check if dict exists
    dict_n = master_dict[dict_n]
    key_n = input("Input key name:\n") # value1, value2
    if key_n in dict_n:
        new_v = input("Input new value:\n")
        dict_n[key_n] = new_v
        print(f"Key {key_n} updated with value {new_v}")
        print(dict_n)
    else:
        print(f"key {key_n} doesn't exit")
else:
    print(f"dict {dict_n} doesn't exit")
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/@lobopt/IcyFirstWatchdog)